# Error cannot find module 'file-saver.js' in node application

Tags: node.js, npm, save-as, filesaver.js

I am trying to use filesaver in my node application where I have run but when I debug I always get the error which reads "Error: Cannot find module 'filesaver.js'.

I have the line `var saveAs = require('filesaver.js');` at the top of my index.js file, and I have also run `npm install file-saver --save` in the terminal - does anyone know how to resolve this?

Edit#1: changed to `var saveAs = require('file-saver.js');` but still getting error as Cannot find module 'file-saver.js'

Edit#2: Tried const { saveAs } = require('file-saver.js'); but still getting same error

Comment: You missed the dash? It's var saveAs = require('file-saver.js')

Comment: `const saveAs = require('file-saver');`

Comment: still not working when I do var saveAs = require('file-saver.js') - is there something else I'm supposed to be installing in the terminal?

Comment: `const { saveAs } = require('file-saver');`

Comment: still same error when I do const { saveAs } = require('file-saver'); instead of var saveAs = require('file-saver.js'); - am I supposed to have both in some capacity?

Comment: Can you post the code?